# how to scaling propotional watermark in image using php

Tags: php

i want to create watermark of all images in my directory, but i have problem with scaling watermark if image fit, small, or large..
if image fit and small ,watermark no propotional.
example i have image with (500*500), watermark (300*300), this not propotional.

this my code

```
$source="source";
$destination="destination";


$watermark=imagecreatefrompng("watermark.png");

$margin_right=10;
$margin_bottom=10;

//Height ($sy) and Width ($sx) of watermark image
$sx=imagesx($watermark);
$sy=imagesy($watermark);

//Get list of images in source folder
$images=array_diff(scandir($source), array('..', '.'));

foreach($images as $image){
//Create image object of main image
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg($source.'/'.$image);

//Copying watermark image into the main image
imagecopy($img, $watermark, imagesx($img) - $sx - $margin_right, imagesy($img) - $sy - $margin_bottom, 0, 0, $sx, $sy);

//Saving the merged image into the destination folder
imagejpeg($img, $destination.'/'.$image,100);

//Destroying the main image object
imagedestroy($img);
}

//Destroying watermark image object
imagedestroy($watermark);
```